# How to open TCP connection in PHP

Tags: php

How to open TCP connection in PHP and send some String over that connection ( for example "test") ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the example from this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php):

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try what? Clicking on the link?

Comment: Try [How to write a good answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 10):

You can create a socket with socket_create, open it with socket_connect and write with socket_write. [socket_write documentation on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php)